# How to configure extbase to fetch inline / IRRE relations to tt_content?

Tags: typo3, persistence, relationship, extbase, typo3-9.x

I've built a extension where I can assign content elements (tt_content) inline (IRRE) to my entries in the TYPO3 Backend.
But I can't figure out how I can resolve the relations so that I can display the assigned content elements in the frontend.

I've created the extension with the 'Extension Builder' in TYPO3 9.5.5.
I created a Model Object 'Content' and selected 'Map to existing table' in the 'Domain object settings' and choosed 'tt_content'.
In my model 'ProductTab' I configured a 1:n relation of type 'Inline (IRRE)' with the name 'content' to my 'Content' model.

If I add content elements to my model entries in the Backend, it works like expected. The relational fields in the DB are mapped correctly. With the 'Extbase Variable Dump' I can see that all my relations are passed to the front end plugin, but my 'content' relation is an empty 'ObjectStorage'.

What am I missing so that the extbase persistence fetches my content relations?

## ext_tables.sql excerpts

```sql
CREATE TABLE tx_myext_domain_model_producttab (
    product int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    title varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    content int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    producttab int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

## TCA excerpts

```php
        'content' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'producttab.content',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'tt_content',
                'foreign_field' => 'producttab',
                'maxitems' => 9999,
                'appearance' => [
                    'collapseAll' => 0,
                    'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                    'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                    'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                    'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
                ],
            ],

        ],
```

Since I can add and edit the content elements in the Backend, I think the DB and TCA relation is fine.
But something is still missing, so that the relation is fetched and provided to the FE template so that I can display the assigned content elements with a ViewHelper.

## ProductTab.php excerpts

```php
class ProductTab extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractValueObject
{
    protected $content = null;
    
    protected function initStorageObjects()
    {
        $this->content = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }

    public function addContent(\MyExt\Domain\Model\Content $content)
    {
        $this->content->attach($content);
    }

    public function removeContent(\MyExt\Domain\Model\Content $contentToRemove)
    {
        $this->content->detach($contentToRemove);
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }
}
```

## Extbase Variable Dump

[Screenshot of debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xZOX.png)

On the screenshot you can see the fetched products (one item in this case) and the producttabs (also 1 item). There is one content element assigned, but the property content of the ProductTab with uid=1 is empty.

## Update

Since I'm still not able to solve this issue, I've created a minimalistic extension with the `Extension Builder` to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/apiening/demo_irrecontent

The extension is the most simple one I could create with one model holding only one property and the relation to `tt_content`. It has a plugin `list` which also shows the debug output.
I've put some more details in the `README.md`of the GitHub project.

Comment: First make sure that on your TCA there is not @lazy parameter present. Then make sure you have assigned a folder via persistence and you have this folder selected in your extension backend view

Comment: Can you also add the relevant parts of your Model (the `content` property and `setContent` and `getContent` functions)?

Comment: Do you have a repository as well?

Comment: I rechecked this: lazyLoading is set to false for all my relations. I have selected a storage folder and my entries gets picked up: I can see all my data of the products, product-tabs etc. with `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` in the frontend, just the assigned content elements are not fetched (empty ObjectStorage object).

Comment: @RudyGnodde I just added the parts of the ProductTab Model which holds the relation to Content / tt_content with the requested `getContent` and `setContent` under **ProductTab.php excerpts**.

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas Yes there is a `ProductRepository`, however this is an empty class that extends `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository` and was generated by the `Extension Builder`. I haven't modified anything here manually. Same is true for the Models: They are just how they've been generated.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your f:debug please?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas I have created a screenshot of the Extbase Variable Dump and linked at the bottom of the question.

Comment: it is a little bit weird. You see, when you place your extension on the backend, then it will be added as tt_content. What happens is that TYPO3 automatically resolves the relation between the tt_content and the product. Then it tries successfully to resolve the producttab and afterwards you go back to tt_content. You should save the tabcontent on its own table and not on tt_content

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas The reason I use tt_content is because I want these elements to have the exact same behaviour like normal content elements. I want to place every content element type, container or plugin to my model and render the assigned CEs in the frontend. I also need multi language support for these elements. All of this basically works, it is just that the uids of the assigned content elements are not fetched.

Comment: When you say content elements, do you mean that it should be like the CE, header, text und media etc?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas yes correct. Also plugins or containers like multirow, accordeon etc. that might hold additional CEs on its own. I can render the CEs in the frontend with a simple ViewHelper, all that I need are the UIDs of the assigned CEs. That's why I need the `content` relation resolved.